# the name file does not exist in current context in signal r Hub class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub, actionresult, fileresult

This is my GetFileData with return type FileResult so it should return a file:

```
public FileResult GetFileData(int fileId)
     {
         var file = db.Files.Single(x => x.Id == fileId);
         return File(file.Content, file.ContentType);
     }
```

**but at last line, its showing red line on File and the error message is--the name file does not exist in current context**. what should i do ??

Answer (score 1):

First:

SignalR isn't for file transfer, it's for sending messages.

[How can I transfer bytes in chunks to clients?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824783/how-can-i-transfer-bytes-in-chunks-to-clients/16307194#16307194)

Second:
File is not working because its declared in System.Web.Mvc.Controller, a SignalR hub doesn't extend this class. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller(v=vs.118).aspx

A Hub extends Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hub 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.hub(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: So, what should i do here if i have to return back file is there any work around? should i place this piece of code somewhere else. i have to make post comment system real time so, my code returns user pic back from db  using this method.I was following this article http://techbrij.com/facebook-wall-posts-comments-knockout-aspnet-webapi any help most appreciated